# Action of maximal compact subgroup on spherical homogeneous space $\DeclareMathOperator\S{SL}\S_2 \times \S_2 \times \S_2 / {\S_2}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, spherical-varieties

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$Allow me to start my question by fixing some notations:

Let $X$ be the spherical homogeneous space $G / H$, where $G = \SL(2, \mathbb{C}) \times \SL(2, \mathbb{C}) \times \SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ and $H = \SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ embedded diagonally in $G$. Let $x_0 = (e, e, e)H$ denote the base point of this homogeneous space ($e$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix). Choose a maximal torus $T$ in $G$; for simplicity, let it be the diagonal matrices in $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ thrice. Let $T_{\mathbb{R}}$ be its real part, $W = N_G(T)/Z_G(T)$ be the Weyl group of $T$ and $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$. There is an obvious action of $W$ on any $T_{\mathbb{R}}$-orbit in $X$. The question is then:

1. Is it possible to choose $K$ such that any $K$-orbit intersects $T_{\mathbb{R}} \cdot x_0$ and its intersection is the unique $W$-orbit?
2. If the answer to the first question is no, then is it possible to additionally choose a point $x_1 \in X$ such that the same fact holds for intersections of $K$-orbits and $T_{\mathbb{R}} \cdot x_1$?

The things I know so far is that it is fairly easy to see that (1) doesn't hold for the obvious choice of $K$ ($K$ being $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ thrice). Also, by tedious calculations, I managed to verify, that (2) doesn't hold for the obvious choice of $K$.

To provide some context for why I need such facts: I'm researching the structure of orbit spaces of maximal compact subgroups on spherical homogeneous spaces and space $X$ is my "example" space: it has quite a simple structure (for instance, its space of $K$-orbits is only three-dimensional), while being non-symmetric. For symmetric spaces (1) is true via $KAH$-decomposition for such $K$ that $K \cap H$ is a maximal compact subgroup in $H$ and such $T$ that $T \cap K$ is a maximal compact torus in $K$.

Comment: Maybe I've got my terminology mixed up, but I always thought that ‘spherical’ referred to the case where $H$ was the fixed-point group of an involution of $G$.  What's the involution in this case?

Comment: @LSpice: What you call "spherical", other mathematicians call "symmetric". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_variety) for the definition of a spherical variety.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466324/action-of-maximal-compact-subgroup-on-spherical-homogeneous-space-sl-2-times-s#comment1209861_466324), thanks!  I guess what caused my mix-up is that ‘spherical character’ is usually used in the setting of symmetric spaces (see, for example, [Murnaghan - Spherical characters: the supercuspidal case](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3509)).